# How to automate sudo password

Tags: sudo

How do you input sudo password automaticly when prompted? I can do this in a script by typing: `echo PASSWORD | sudo -S Command`, but how do I do that always when prompted?

Comment: Have you read http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1510272 ?

Comment: Do the same: `echo PASSWORD | sudo -S Command`. What's the problem?

Comment: But always, even not in a script, like when i click on somthing like the update manager, i would not like to insert the paswd, so what to do?, a week a go i say a video on youtube, a guy had done this but i can't remeber what the video was called, so how do you do it?

Comment: Found a way, Add "echo Password | sudo -S pwd" to the file /home/username/.bashrc att the end of the line, you will now never have to input your password in terminal again

Comment: Just configure sudo to not require a password, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can modify the sudoers file (using `visudo`) and use the "NOPASSWD" option to not prompt for a password. From, [here](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) page; e.g. `man sudoers` and searching for NOPASSWD -

> NOPASSWD and PASSWD
>
> By default, sudo requires that a user authenticate him or herself before running a command. This behavior can be modified via the NOPASSWD tag. Like a Runas_Spec, the NOPASSWD tag sets a default for the commands that follow it in the Cmnd_Spec_List. Conversely, the PASSWD tag can be used to reverse things. For example:

```
ray     rushmore = NOPASSWD: /bin/kill, /bin/ls, /usr/bin/lprm
```

> would allow the user ray to run /bin/kill, /bin/ls, and /usr/bin/lprm as root on the machine rushmore without authenticating himself. If we only want ray to be able to run /bin/kill without a password the entry would be:

```
ray     rushmore = NOPASSWD: /bin/kill, PASSWD: /bin/ls, /usr/bin/lprm
```

> Note, however, that the PASSWD tag has no effect on users who are in the group specified by the exempt_group option.
>
> By default, if the NOPASSWD tag is applied to any of the entries for a user on the current host, he or she will be able to run ''sudo -l'' without a password. Additionally, a user may only run ''sudo -v'' without a password if the NOPASSWD tag is present for all a user's entries that pertain to the current host. This behavior may be overridden via the verifypw and listpw options.

Comment: you shold, IMO , ALWAYS edit with visudo , visudo checks syntax

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Edited. That's **great** advice.